# Recovery of data on iPhone with Ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery, ubuntu-sdk, iphone, user-data, terminal-server

I have lost the data on my iPhone. Unfortunately I don't have a backup.

Can I use Ubuntu to recover it?  SMS-es, photos, etc?
If this is possible, then how can I do this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "[recovery](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recovery)"? Did you lost it somewhere?

Comment: Recovery date or all of information

Comment: How did you lost your data exactly? Or do you want to make a backup? Have you tried with [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)?

Comment: Yes I want recover my old date .. And no I'm not tried

Comment: Is your device bricked now? If so, do you have a backup stored somewhere where you can get your data from? If not, probably the unique valid option is to follow the [official guide for recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263), on a system that Apple supports (and that is not Ubuntu, since they do not support Linux OSs).

Comment: Is there any programmed recovery  in Ubuntu ?

Comment: The problem is not on the Ubuntu side, but on the device side. Unfortunately for you, it is really uncompatible with other operating systems than the one decided by Apple and if Apple decide that Ubuntu is not compatible with its programs, than there is nothing that we can do.

Comment: Yes I want recover my old date and i dont have backup ?

Comment: I don't know of other tools apart from iTunes, which does not support Linux. We wait for someone else that knows better than me :)

Comment: Tanks for you answer dadexix86